# How to remove the last digit after the some symbols in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For input

> A.B.1.23

I want output

> A.B.1

Comment: Is this u r looking for 

DECLARE @ AS VARCHAR(100) = 'A.B.1.23'
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@),0)+1,LEN(REVERSE(@))))

Comment: What are other "some symbols" in your data aside from dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
select left(col, len(col) - charindex('.', reverse(col)))
```

This is dynamic and simply assumes that there is at least on `'.'` in the column.

Comment: THIS ALSO WORKS

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps..

```
DECLARE @ AS VARCHAR(100) = 'A.B.1.23'
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@),0)+1,LEN(REVERSE(@))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also :

```
DECLARE @ AS VARCHAR(100) = 'A.B.1.23'
select substring(@, 1, len(@) - charindex('.', reverse(@)))
```